# javac can't find jar files that have been installed in jre/lib/ext

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, java-3d

I want to try out the Java3D library and have used the installer to auto-install them for me (I'm running windows). I was using Elipse and noticed that it couldn't find the packages. I tried compiling a class outside of Eclipse from the command line and has the same issues there.

The installer has definitely put the jar files in my java-sdk/jre/lib/ext folder so I'm not sure why it isn't automatically detecting them as I thought that this folder was automatically searched.

I then manually added the jar to the classpath by setting the CLASSPATH environment variable and the program outside of Eclipse then worked. Eclipse still couldn't find them, so I added the jars to my Eclipse project and it works.

The thing I'd really like to know is why I had to set the CLASSPATH environment variable when the jars were installed in the jre/lib/ext folder.

Other information is that I notice that there's no JAVA_HOME variable in my environment variables. Should there be? This might be the problem.

Also, just for interest (and learning) I notice in the Java installation that there is a JRE folder inside the Java-SDK-1.6.xxx folder and also another one in the same directory as the Java-SDK-1.6.xxx folder. Why is this?

Many thank in advance.

Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this .

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html

Comment: Irrelevant, but I learnt this the very hard way. :-) `The current directory is NOT included in the Unix's PATH implicitly. You need to include "." in the PATH environment variable explicitly. On the other hand, current directory is included in Windows' PATH implicitly.`

Answer (score 1):

Without `JAVA_HOME` environment variable java Extensions classloader is unable to find path to `jre/lib/ext` dir. Because, by default, the extensions class loader loads the code in the `<JAVA_HOME>/lib/ext`.

See [Java Classloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) for more details.